# what does Label's texture and texture_size mean?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to know what does Label's texture_size mean. it confuse me because of following code

my.kv

```
<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            padding: 100, 100
            text: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n'*2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qmde.gif)

if I change my.kv

```
<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            #height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            padding: 100, 100
            text: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n'*2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPHqd.gif)

although reading document about texture,I don't know why I need to set 'height' by using texture_size and what does Label's texture size mean.Can anyone help me to understand it? Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping):

> the text image (texture) is only just large enough to contain the
> characters and is positioned in the center of the Label.

The `texture` is what contains the `text` for display. The `texture_size` is the size of that `texture`

You don't have to set the `height` to `self.texture_size[1]`. That sets the height to just big enough to contain the `texture`.

In your second example code, your are setting `size_hint_y` to `None` and not setting the `height` of the `Label`. The result of that is that the `Label` is left with its default height of `100`. Note that `texture` of the `Label` is still large enough to contain the `text`, so it is much larger than the `Label` itself. The enclosing `ScrollView` uses the `height` of the `Label` for its operation, and since that `height` does not reflect the height of the `texture`, its operation appears incorrect.

In the first example code, you are setting the `height` of the `Label` to reflect the height of the `texture`. This results in a `Label` with a much larger `height` (that contains the `texture`) and allows the `ScrollView` to operate correctly.

To more clearly see this, try changing your `kv` to:

```
<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            #height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            padding: 100, 100
            text: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n'*2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

The above code just adds a `canvas` instruction to highlight the actual size of the `Label`. Try running your code with this `kv` and again with the `height` line uncommented.

Comment: but whether set the height to self.texture_size[1] or not will influence result(I add the difference result in article)